# Why is this ideal diode bridge rectifier simulation in LTSpice not working as expected?

Tags: diodes, bridge-rectifier, rms, alternator, full-bridge

I'm trying to simulate a full wave bridge rectifier circuit with the capacitor filter. The alternating voltage supply is 30 V at 50 Hz.[image: Schematic created using LTSpice]

[image: Simulation result]

The peak value for the voltage across the load is 28.5 V. However, I don't get how that's possible. Is it the RMS voltage or the average voltage across it?
[image: Simulation result after load resistance is increased to 30 kΩ]

After increasing the load to 30 kΩ, I tend to get the same plot as before. I'd expect the graph to smoothen out as the rate of discharge has decreased due to a rise in load resistance and hence the time constant should increase but this has clearly not happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what is happening on your side, but I get an error message:

> Error on line 850 : .model idealdiode d(ron=0 roff=1 meg vfwd=0.7)
> * Unrecognized parameter "meg" -- ignored

You can't have a space after `Roff=1`, it has to be `Roff=1meg`. Then the result will change to the expected output.

Comment: This is the reason. OP should have seen the error log popping up. It's also the reason why thre's ripple with a 1k load. And also that timestep is ridiculous (and the cause for the low resolution of the waveform). OP, next time try plotting more than one single waveform, try t debug the circuit yourself. And it wouldn't hurt to avoid `Ron=0`, to avoid possible convergence issues (fortunately, this circuit is simple enough, but more complex ones may crash and the engine may not point at the true cause).

Answer (score 1):

> *The peak value for the voltage across the load is 28.5V.However, I
> don't get how thats possible. Is it the RMS voltage or the average
> voltage across it?*

The peak DC voltage is the peak AC voltage minus two diode volt drops. 28.5 volts DC sounds exactly what I would expect with a 30 volt peak AC signal.

> *After increasing the load to 30kΩ,I tend to get the same plot as
> before.I'd expect the graph to smoothen out as the rate of discharge
> has decreased due to a rise in load resistance and hence the time
> constant should increase but this has clearly not happened.*

I expect that you may not have changed the resistor value to 30 kΩ.

Comment: When I change capacitance values, the graph changes. However, for a constant capacitance value, changing the resistor values has no effect on the graph.

Comment: Ensure that the capacitor and resistor both connect to the ground symbol. At the moment they don't look like they do. But, I can assure you that the value of the resistor is not being changed.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that your 30V SPICE source setting is  30V peak (+/-30V) so it corresponds to 21.2V RMS for a sine wave.

Also, your ripple voltage is insanely large for a 40,000uF capacitor and 1K load. Something is very wrong- something seems to be drawing amperes not mA (or the cap is not 40,000uF). About 14mVp-p is expected (back of the envelope manual calculation) with a 1k\$\Omega\$ load. Your plot shows several volts, which is hundreds of times too much.

I suggest you name the output node to make sure you are not measuring some other schematic.